# Make entire row clickable

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

I am trying to make the entire row of a table clickable. I have looked at a bunch of tutorials and they all seem pretty simple but I can't seem to get it to work. I tried DoNav and that didn't work, the simple onclick attribute doesn't work, what am I doing wrong? I am using mysql, php, and html. Thank you for your help!

```
echo '<table>';
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<th>Name</th><th>Checked In?</th><th>ID</th>';
        echo '</tr>';
         while($row = $CheckedIn->fetch_assoc()){

            echo '<tr onmouseover="ChangeColor(this, true);" onmouseout="ChangeColor(this,false);" onclick="document.location="www.engineering.us/gena/details.php";">';
            echo '<td align="left">';

            echo $row['ChildName'];

            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td align="center">';
        ;
            echo $row['checkedin'];

            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td align="center">';

            echo $row['P_Id'];

            echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';

    }
    echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picking up from what **georoot** said, use PHP within your HTML. It makes the markup a lot more readable and usually allows your program to add syntax highlighting, making it easier to read. I've added two additional classes ("`js-table`" and "`table-tr`") which I'll explain in a bit. Another important point is that the URL is in a new attribute on the table row: `data-url`.

```
<table class="js-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Checked In?</th>
            <th>ID</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php while ($row = $CheckedIn->fetch_assoc()): ?>
        <tr class="table-tr" data-url="http://www.engineering.us/gena/details.php">
            <td><?php echo $row['ChildName']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['checkedin']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['P_Id']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The "`table-tr`" class allows us to target the table rows in CSS. There is no need to use JavaScript for something so simple. Even changing the colour of the text within the table cell is very easy in CSS. This technique has the other advantage that it can be easily changed without having to modify any HTML, PHP or JavaScript - it's a purely stylistic thing.

```
.table-tr:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Finally, since you're using jQuery, we can take advantage of that new "`js-table`" class. The "js-" prefix states that the class is used for binding functionality and it should not be styled. This script simply bind a click event to the table that listens out for a user clicking on a table row with the `data-url` attribute. When that happens, the page is re-directed (using `window.location` instead of `document.location` - it may work either way, but I've always used `window.location`) to that URL. This allows you to change the URL later on or change it per row without having to change any of your JavaScript.

```
$(function () {

    $(".js-table").on("click", "tr[data-url]", function () {
        window.location = $(this).data("url");
    });

});
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! I am very new to this, I have some HTML experience but no PHP or mysql and barely any javascript. I don't even really know what jQuery is. Where should I put the jQuery code block?

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library. I'd recommend learning JavaScript before jQuery, but that's outside the scope of this question. The jQuery code should either be put inside a `<script> ... </script>` tag on the page (either in the `<head>` tag or near the bottom of the `<body>`) or added to an external JavaScript file and adding to the `<head>` tag in the form `<script src="..."></script>`

Comment: @JamesLong does deserve a vote up for the extensive answer provided :)

Answer (score 3):

```
onclick="document.location="www.engineering.us/gena/details.php";"
```

this should be

```
onclick="document.location='www.engineering.us/gena/details.php';"
```

Also another tip, you have more HTML than php, so it is better to use multiple php tags rather than echo called many times. That way it would be little easier to find such mistakes.

*Edit*
You should also escape the apostrophe in case you are still going with php

Comment: I have tried that it just makes the entire site crash

Comment: @georoot if you put a `'` in the text, it will end the `echo '` - thus crash badly.  Another reason to use HTML with php tags.

Comment: @freedomn-m thats why i edited my answer ;) Should mention that also , i assumed it was understood because it was more or less similar problem

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to do that with JQuery.

HTML

```
<tr class="table-tr"></tr>
```

JQuery

```
$('.table-tr').on('click', function(){
    window.location = "your url here";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the following code:

```
$("#Table tr").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    var value = $(this).find('td:first').html();
    window.location.href = "url";
});
```

Where Table is the your table name and url is the address you want to navigate to

Answer (score -1):

Please Change your code with this

```
<tr onclick="window.location.href=www.engineering.us/gena/details.php">
```